# echo removes leading whitespace in a Bash variable

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

Newbie to bash here. I'm hoping to prepend a single whitespace to a variable in bash, currently I have the following, which doesn't seem to work:

```
space=`printf '%1s' ' '`
mystr='hello'

mystr="$space$mystr"
echo $mystr
```

So instead of printing out "hello", I would like the result to be " hello", which has an additional whitespace at the beginning. What's the correct way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: `space=' '` is sufficient; you don't need to call `printf`.

Comment: This is also [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The leading space is being removed by shell because of word splitting. Enclose your variable in double quotes to disable word splitting:

```
echo "$mystr"
```

---

See this post: [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

See these docs as well: [Word Splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) and [Field Splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_05)